# A vector calculus formula

Tags: differential-calculus, exterior-algebra

Let me answer my own question, hoping to be forgiven for that.
I asked unsuccessfully that question [on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200508/a-vector-calculus-formula). Let $A, B$ be vector fields in $\mathbb R^3$. 
We have
$$
\text{curl}\bigl((A\cdot \nabla)B\bigr)=(A\cdot \nabla)\text{curl}B
-((\text{curl}B)\cdot \nabla)A+(\text{div} A)\ \text{curl} B+\sum_{1\le j\le 3}
\nabla a_j\times\nabla b_j,
$$
with the notation 
$
V=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix}.
$
I find the last term quite unpleasant and I wonder if it could be expressed in terms of  curl, div of $A,B$.

Comment: Generally one should wait more than just two days before crossposting.

Comment: some like to use the notation $\nabla_A$ to denote the gradient operator acting on the vector $A$, and then $\sum_{1\le j\le 3}
\nabla a_j\times\nabla b_j=(\nabla_A\times\nabla_B)(A\cdot B)$.